# Restricting access to Java classes in JRuby script

Tags: security, jruby

I want to allow client to write scripts in JRuby and run them on web server. Is there a way to disable java-jruby integration. Or at least a way to disable access to ceratain classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [`org.jruby.Profile`](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/Profile.html) interface. With this you can implement a custom version that disallows loading certain files or classes. As the comments suggest above, disallowing load of "java" should be enough to disable Java integration.

You can set the runtime profile with `org.jruby.RubyInstanceConfig#setProfile` before the runtime is initialized. If you're using the `org.jruby.embed` APIs, then use `org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer#setProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowing a user to submit a file and have your server execute it as a script?  That's probably a very bad idea for several reasons.  To begin with, what is it they could do in Java that you don't want them to, that they could not do in plain ruby?

With that being said, ensure a script does not have `require 'java'` in it will prevent Java integration.

Comment: I can imagine they they could somehow get access to DB communication layer and mess with my data. I have tested require 'java' and it turned out that it is not needed to instantiate any java class. import 'abc.dbc.def.SomeClass' is enough.

Comment: Can you check your shell environment vars RUBYOPTS and JRUBY_OPTS.  If I try `s = java.lang.String` without doing `require 'java'` first, I get a NameError

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention that JRuby is embedded into my Java application, so probably I may initialize everything with some different config that standalone installation. So of course scripts that users submit execute in the same JVM as the whole webapp.